# How to run function only when service variable state changed in component Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have service called as InfoFormService and it has a variable called isInValidating.

The variable is set as true when component invoke validateEmail(email) function as below.

```
@Injectable()
export class InfoFormService {

    private VALIDATE_EMAIL_URL: string = 'XXX';
    isInValidating: boolean = false;

    constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: AppConfig,
                private http:Http
    ) {

      console.log(this.config.apiEndpoint)

    }

    validateEmail(email) {
      console.log(email)
      this.isInValidating = true;
      return this.http.get(`${this.config.apiEndpoint}/${this.VALIDATE_EMAIL_URL}${email}`)
    }

}
```

And the component invoke validateEmail whenever email input text changed.

Because ValidateEmail takes time, when I click submit button, the isInValidating value might be true or false, but once ValidateEmail action completed, the isInValidating value will set as false as above code.

What I want is to delay submit action which happens when click Submit button until service's isInValidating value set as true.

```
export class AbcBtnComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private formService:InfoFormService) {

    }

    ...

    emailField.valueChanges
      .filter(val => {
        return val.length >= 1;
      })
      .debounceTime(100)
      .switchMap(val => this.formService.validateEmail(val))
      .subscribe(res => {

        console.log(res)
        let validation = res.json();

        if (validation['valid']) {
          emailField.setErrors(null);
        } else {
          emailField.setErrors({ validEmail: true });
        }

        this.formService.isInValidating = false;

      });

    onSubmit(value) {
        // Here I want to delay until formService's isInValidating value = true

        submitAction(value)
    }

}
```

I guess that I have to use Subject or Observable, but have no idea how to use it.

Please help me!

Comment: Why not just store the submit value in the component temporarily until the isInValidating is set to false, and then right after the line that sets it to false, add a call to another method that actually submits the cached data?

Comment: You seems to submit data just after isInValidating become false at anytime, but I want to do it when I click submit button.
And how to detect isInValidating changed to false is just problem and the goal of this question.

Comment: I misread the question, sorry. What sets 'isInValidating' to true? I dont see anything that sets it to true in the code, only something that sets to false. Does the form service do it behind the scenes? If so, you should be able to subscribe to it and watch it for changes and submit the form then, but even with that method you'd probably still be better off caching the submission until its ready to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In component

```
get isInValidating(): boolean {
    return this.formService.isInValidating;
}
```

In template

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="isInValidating">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.formService.validateEmail(val))
      .subscribe(res => {

this.formService.validateEmail(val)
      .subscribe(res => {
..)
```

Technically if you subscribe to the validateEmail call and execute your code there, it should work. But I might have missunderstood your question.

You could also just remove the isInValidating and have the onSubmit(value) inside like:

```
this.formService.validateEmail(val)).subscribe(res => {
//logic to check your validation
if(valid) this.onSubmit(val)
});
```